# Did the current president of the Philippines clean up the city of Davao and if so, how?

Tags: police

The city of Davao in southern Mindanao, Philippines is a very safe city. You can walk almost anywhere there at any time of day or night.

But Davao is situated in an area that is very dangerous for foreigners. The risk of kidnapping (often by Muslim guerrilla Abu Sayyaf) outside Davao is considerable for a foreigner, to say the least.

The "quick story" on this is that the long time Mayor of Davao, Rody Duterte, is a "strong man" that used death squads to "clean out the trash". (This image has now even made him the president of the Philippines.)

Having lived in the Philippines and also visited Davao, my impression is that death squads are more a South American way of resolving security issues. I just intuitively ask myself if death squads are the (whole?) explanation to the good security situation in Davao.

Social and political issues are often complicated with many factors involved. I therefore ask how this extraordinary situation has occurred. How can Davao (the largest city in the area) be a safe city in such dangerous surroundings?

A related issue is if Mayor Duterte, recently elected the president of the Philippines, could apply any of his methods to the entire country. (Which I personally doubt, just as an intuitive guess.)

Comment: "MANILA, Aug. 3 (UPI) -- Several hundred people have been killed in a drug crackdown since Philippines President Rodrigo Duterte was elected in May." - Considering how liberally drugs like meth used to be sold and also the suspected connections between authorities and drug dealers, I find this news very strange.

Comment: Duterte: "If you know of any addicts, go ahead and kill them yourself as getting their parents to do it would be too painful.” - If you just knew how many are on meth in the Philippines!